# Alien Invasion Game Settings object has no attribute 'alien_points'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in need for help in this python code. I don't know what's wrong as I've checked everything is working correctly with all the imports in place.

This is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 51, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 43, in run_game
    gf.update_bullets(bullets, aliens, ai_settings, screen, ship, stats, sb)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\game_functions.py", line 66, in update_bullets
    check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, aliens, bullets, screen, ship, stats, sb)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\game_functions.py", line 163, in check_bullet_alien_collisions
    stats.score += ai_settings.alien_points * len(aliens)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'alien_points'
```

Now I will outline th code:

Main code (alien_invasion.py):

```
import sys
import game_functions as gf
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group
from alien import Alien
from game_stats import GameStats
from button import Button
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    play_button = Button(ai_settings, screen, "Play")

    stats = GameStats(ai_settings)
    sb = Scoreboard(ai_settings, screen, stats)
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    aliens = Group()
    bullets = Group()

    # Background color
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)


    while True:

        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, stats, play_button, aliens)
        if stats.game_active:
            ship.update(ai_settings)
            gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship, stats, screen, bullets)
            gf.update_bullets(bullets, aliens, ai_settings, screen, ship, stats, sb)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship, aliens, stats, play_button, sb)





run_game()
```

Alien code (alien.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Alien, self).__init__()

        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\alien.bmp')
        #Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Start each new alienn near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        #Store the alien's exact position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        #Draw the alien at its current location
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor * self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True
```

Bullet code(bullet.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.ship_speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.ship_speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y


    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Button code(button.py):

```
import pygame.font

class Button():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, msg):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.width, self.height = 200, 50
        self.button_color = (0, 250, 0)
        self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect.center = (self.screen_rect.center)
        self.prep_msg(msg)

    def prep_msg(self, msg):
        self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg, True, self.text_color, self.button_color)
        self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
        self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def draw_button(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.button_color, self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.msg_image, self.msg_image_rect)
```

Game functions(game_functions.py):

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from time import sleep
from settings import Settings
from button import Button

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, stats, play_button, aliens):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            check_play_button(stats, play_button, ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y)




def update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship, aliens, stats, play_button, sb):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    if not stats.game_active:
        play_button.draw_button()

    aliens.draw(screen)
    ship.blitme(screen)
    sb.show_score()
    pygame.display.flip()

def check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
        if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet =  Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
            bullets.add(new_bullet)


def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def update_bullets(bullets, aliens, ai_settings, screen, ship, stats, sb):
    bullets.update()
    check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, aliens, bullets, screen, ship, stats, sb)
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)
    if len(aliens) == 0:
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)


def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)
    for row_number in range(number_rows):

        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - (ship_height))
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows

def update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship, stats, screen, bullets):
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, aliens):
        ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
    check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
            break

def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    if stats.ships_left > 0:
        stats.ships_left -= 1

    else:
        stats.game_active = False
        stats.game_over = True
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    aliens.empty()
    bullets.empty()

    create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)
    ship.center_ship

    sleep(0.5)

def check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            break

def check_play_button(stats, play_button, ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    button_clicked = play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if button_clicked and not stats.game_active:
        stats.game_active = True
        stats.reset_stats()
        aliens.empty()
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)
        ship.center_ship()

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, aliens, bullets, screen, ship, stats, sb):
    # Check for collision with aliens
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(aliens, bullets, True, True)
    if collisions:
        for aliens in collisions.values():
            stats.score += ai_settings.alien_points * len(aliens)
            sb.prep_score()
        check_high_score(stats)
    if len(aliens) == 0:
        # New level
        stats.level += 1
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, aliens, screen, ship)
        ai_settings.increase_speed(2)
```

Game stats (game_stats.py):

```
class GameStats():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings):
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.reset_stats()
        self.game_active = False

    def reset_stats(self):
        self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
        self.score = 0
        self.level = 1
        self.score = 0
```

Scoreboard code (scoreboard.py):

```
import pygame.font

class Scoreboard():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, stats):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.stats = stats
        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        self.prep_score()

    def prep_score(self):
        score_str = str(self.stats.score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True, self.text_color, self.ai_settings.bg_color)
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20
        rounded_score = int(round(self.stats.score, -1))
        score_str = "{:,}".format(rounded_score)

    def show_score(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
```

Settings code (settings.py):

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 10
        self.ship_limit = 3

        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 12
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3

        self.alien_speed_factor = 2
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        self.fleet_x_margin = 70
        self.fleet_y_margin = 70
        self.fleet_direction = -1

        self.speedup_scale = 1.1
        self.score_scale = 1.5


def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 3
    self.alien_speed_factor = 1
    self.fleet_direction = 1
    self.alien_points = 50

def increase_speed(self):
    self.ship_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    self.bullet_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    self.alien_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    self.alien_points = int(self.alien_points * self.score_scale)
```

Ship code (ship.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Ship(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Ship, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor



    def update(self, ai_settings):
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
            self.rect.centerx -= 1


    def blitme(self, screen):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def center_ship(self):
        self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

Any help would really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The error is telling you that `ai_settings` is a `Settings()` object, and that settings object doesn;t have an attribute associated with it called `alien_points`. Where in your code do you set that attribute, or what in the documentation tells you that you can call `alien_points` as an attribute of `Settings()` objects?

Comment: The attribute is being set in the settings.py file inside the function `def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):` right?

Comment: You don;t appear to be calling the method `ai_settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()` in the code you've shown, which would initialize the settings inside the object. Unless this is something automatic with pygame that I'm not aware of

Comment: It was fixed already. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py You had forgotten to put initialize_dynamic_settings() into **init**

class
class Settings():
def **init**(self):
--snip--
**self.initialize_dynamic_settings()**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).